# How to format code so while loop is triggered C

Tags: c, while-loop, formatting, boolean-logic

So I have two while loops. The outer most one does not loop back the way I want it to.

I first tried:

```
#define true 1
#define false 0
```

But then  set it to what I did below.

My problem is that when I run the program, it terminates after an invalid input. I would like it to loop back to the start if something incorrect is entered.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int user_number;//create a new integer variable
    int last_multiple;//create a new integer variable for max in mult table
    int stilltrue = "false"; //create integer to use in while
    while (stilltrue == "false"){//initiate while loop
    printf("Please enter a positive integer you would like the table for and"
           " hit enter, then enter the max value of its multiplication "
           "table: \n");
//takes two inputs and makes sure they are integers
    if(scanf("%d",&user_number) == 1 && scanf("%d",&last_multiple)== 1){
        printf("The number you typed was %d and the "
           " value was %d \n\n",user_number,last_multiple);

    while (last_multiple > 0){

        int multiple;//multiple of user_number and last_multiple
        multiple = user_number * last_multiple;
        printf("%d x %d is %d \n\n", user_number,last_multiple,multiple);
        last_multiple = last_multiple - 1;//decrease the last_multiple value by 1
        stilltrue = "true";
    }

    } else {
        printf("That was not an integer. \n");
        stilltrue = "false"; //This isn't needed here

    }break;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

So what do I modify to make it loop back if it makes it to this spot

```
else {
        printf("That was not an integer. \n");
        stilltrue = "false"; //This isn't needed here

    }
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You should get a few compiler warnings about invalid conversions/... since you are assigning/comparing strings to integers.

Comment: Use `true` and `false` instead of `"true"` and `"false"`.

`"true"` is a string (or a char array as you prefer)

and `true` is a call to your define

Comment: Can you please explain why are you using quotes?

Comment: Apart from compiler errors, the line with `break` is breaking your outer loop.

Comment: I did the quotes because after defining a true and false, it would just skip over everything. I set the int to a string just as a value that could be checked or returned.

Comment: If I delete that last break, then I get an infinitely repeating text output in my command window. I'm using codeblocks and am not getting any compiler errors.

Comment: @WadeRosko It doesn't makes any sense. Did you even try to print your int values to see what is wrong ? You should.

Comment: In these two pictures you see the plain true false and how nothing appears in the cmd window, and then the outcome of the quoted one. imgur.com/a/Ap62C

Comment: Also, how do you plan to terminate the program? Means, how can a user exit from the program?

Comment: Just put back these 2 lines `int stilltrue = false;` and `while (stilltrue == false)` but without the quotes, it's the only thing you have to change, just remove the quotes, nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If scanf fails when reading an integer, the input buffer needs to be cleared of the character causing the failure. The scanset `"%*[^\n]"` scans and discards characters that are not newline. A newline is left in the input buffer but the `%d` format specifier will skip leading whitespace.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define true 1
#define false 0

int main()
{
    int user_number;//create a new integer variable
    int last_multiple;//create a new integer variable for max in mult table
    int stilltrue = false; //create integer to use in while
    while (stilltrue == false){//initiate while loop
        printf("Please enter a positive integer you would like the table for and"
        " hit enter, then enter the max value of its multiplication "
        "table: \n");
        //takes two inputs and makes sure they are integers
        if ( ( scanf("%d %d", &user_number, &last_multiple)) == 2){
            printf("The number you typed was %d and the "
            " value was %d \n\n",user_number,last_multiple);

            while (last_multiple > 0){
                int multiple;//multiple of user_number and last_multiple
                multiple = user_number * last_multiple;
                printf("%d x %d is %d \n\n", user_number,last_multiple,multiple);
                last_multiple = last_multiple - 1;//decrease the last_multiple value by 1
                stilltrue = true;
            }

        } else {
            printf("That was not an integer. \n");
            stilltrue = false; //This isn't needed here
            scanf ( "%*[^\n]");//clear input buffer of all characters up to newline
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That works great. Thank you. Why is the **scanf ( "%*[^\n]");** necessary/ what does it do in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define true 1
#define false 0
```

These are directives and `#define` directive causes the compiler to substitute token-string for each occurrence of identifier in the source file.

Simply use `true` or `false` instead `"true"` and `"false"`. By using them as `"true"` or `"false"` they will be treated as string. Therefore your loop is not iterating.

Comment: That's what I did initially, but it ends up not prompting the user for any information and does not print anything when it runs.

Comment: You have to simply assign the value as `int stilltrue = false;` and while loop condition  will be simply as `while(stilltrue)`. The condition are basically an expression which finally has to be evaluated as `true` ie. `non-zero` in C and `false` ie. `zero` in C.

Comment: @WadeRosko It is because you don't have remove your `break` statement yet.

Comment: I did that, and then also tried another variant of it without the quotes. In these two pictures you see the plain true false and how nothing appears in the cmd window, and then the outcome of the quoted one. http://imgur.com/a/Ap62C

Comment: one more thing `scanf` return the number of characters written. Therefore, in case some one inputted integer of more than two digits . `if` condition in first `while` loop will fail.

Comment: It does not fail. I can enter any int regardless of its length and the program runs and displays each output. I'm just stuck trying to get the program to loop back to asking for the number if someone does not input a number.

Comment: First adopt the above suggested changes. `stilltrue = "true";` remove this line from the body of second `while` loop. And set the value of `stilltrue` in `else` as `stilltrue = false;` and do remove the `break` too. First `while` condition can be anything `stilltrue == false` or `!stilltrue`. Adopt these changes.

Comment: @AmitSharma: `scanf` returns the number of successful conversions and assignments, not characters read.  `scanf("%d",&user_number) == 1` will work for any number of digits (up to the max supported by `int`, anyway).

Comment: @JohnBode Yeah.. Thanks. True it is `printf` which returns the number of char written. Whereas `scanf` returns the no. of successful conversion and assignment.

Answer (score 0):

```
int stilltrue = "false"; //create integer to use in while
while (stilltrue == "false"){//initiate while loop
```

Those lines will absolutely *not* do what you want, and your compiler should have complained about the initialization of `stilltrue` in the declaration.  `"false"` is a *string literal*, not the `false` symbol that you defined earlier.

Change those to

```
int stilltrue = false; //create integer to use in while
while (stilltrue == false){//initiate while loop
```

or better,

```
int stilltrue = false;
while ( !stilltrue ) {
```

Note that `true` and `false` are already defined in `stdbool.h`; there's no need to define them on your own.